# How to safely close a large c application in linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, shutdown

I have large multi threaded c application , which basically does so many works, like local server, sql database communication, sip, and etc running on linux. 
I want to shutdown the linux machine, using "sudo shutdown -h now"

shall i close, my c application before shutting down system? what is the safe way to close my application.

If I close my application using "sudo kill -9 pID", then may be i loss some state of my application , my system may go into bad state.

For example: suppose i am reading and writing from a file in c, and shutdown commands come, what will happen? should I detect shutdown siganl from my code, and close file first then shutdown.? what is the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Designing a proper shutdown scheme into an application is very difficult if it's an afterthought after the application is finished. Organized shutdown should be built into the architecture from the very beginning.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Or, if you are Google, you design your application such that an ordinary shutdown is no different from an application crash (bot cases do not loose data).

Comment: What?  Only you know what your app requirements are.  If it does not matter if files are not flushed in your app, then who cares?

Answer (score 4):

The `shutdown` command initiates a shutdown procedure (traditionally by invoking `init 0` but that might be no longer the case with systemd). This shutdown procedure consists roughly of the following parts:

1. Disallow anyone from logging in
2. Send a `SIGTERM` to all processes and wait a couple of seconds
3. Send a `SIGKILL` to all processes and wait a couple of seconds
4. Write all unwritten changes to disk
5. turn off the system

If your program needs to react to a shutdown, the best way is to catch the `SIGTERM` the operating system sens you. When you get a `SIGTERM`, assume that someone wants you to terminate. Once you got a `SIGTERM`, write all changes to disk and safely shut down your application. Try not to make this process too complex as the system only gives you a limited time to react to a `SIGTERM`.

In general though, your program should deal with either itself or the system unexpectedly crashing. It should be written in a way that it can recover from a system crash with having inconsistent data structures. This is hard to get right and even a basic explanation of the strategies to do that would be too much for this answer.

Comment: Oh, please have an upboat for the last paragraph!  Apps that cannot survive unexpected, unmanaged shutdowns are of bad  quality:)

Comment: Similarly, operating systems that cannot survive unexpected, unmanaged shutdowns are of bad quality.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is for your application to handle the `SIGTERM` signal, by setting a "shutdown" flag in its handler. In order to be safe against partial reads and writes, always use the `volatile sig_atomic_t` type for that purpose.

On each iteration of the main loop you should be checking this flag and if it is set, stop accepting new connections and start releasing any resources and/or closing any connections. After you consider your program to be in a clean state, simply call `exit`.

`kill -9` sends a `SIGKILL` which cannot be handled by a process and performs an ungraceful kill. It just interrupts your program at whatever instruction it was and calls the OS to clean after it.